# How do I create a 3 week rotating schedule from SQL data? - EDITED

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

I am in the process of building an application for a cafeteria that uses a 3 week rotating menu. Here is the DB structure in a nutshell:

```
Foodnum(int - PK - auto incrementing field)
FoodName(nvarchar - name of an Item)
FoodStation(nvarchar - name of station in cafeteria i.e grill, entree, salad bar)
WeekNum(int field -  containing 1 - 3)
DayNum(int field - containing 1 - 7)
```

How would I go about rotating the following for 3 weeks then looping(to start it over) without storing a start date in sql. Is this even possible?

**Edited**
I have just created another table and all it has in a column called startdate is the value of a label set to datetime.now. so its value is currently 2013-06-07 14:24:08.000

Comment: if you don't store a start date, you can only got from other known or easily derived "known" start points, e.g. "today", "oldest date in table", "newest date in table", etc...

Comment: I edited my previous question. I added another table to my Database that only contains the start date

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@user185791 this is what I ended up using. Many thanks and kudos for the point in the right direction. I felt it to be useful to add this answer in as I know there will be someone else who will find this useful.

```
WHERE [WeekNum] = (DATEPART(WEEK, GETDATE()) % 3) + 1 AND [DayNum] = DATEPART(DW, GETDATE())
```

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 3):

What if you keep the same structure, and in the where clause of the query do something like

```
WHERE WeekNum = (DATEPART(WEEK, GETDATE()) % 3) + 1
```

That way you always get a number from 1 - 3. Today we are on week 23, so it would be the Menu from week 3.

Comment: This is the same basic solution I would approach this problem with as well.  It's simple; easily maintained, and easily understood.  Good job.

Comment: @user1845791 are you suggesting to ditch the start date?

Comment: @Skullomania it would depend on your exact requirements, but I think you do not need a start date. This would be based on the week number in the year. Just one thing to consider, it could affect you when a year ends, for example December 29 - 31, 2013 is week 53, the query would select menu #3, then Wednesday is January 1, 2014 (and start of week #1), and the query would return menu #2. Every other week in the year would work correctly.

Comment: That gets the week perfectly but is off on the day it is pulling the item on the 5th day of the week instead of today

Comment: @user1845791 I took your answer and expanded on it. I upvoted your question because I could not have done it without your help